# copy table from one SQL server 2005 to another SQL Server 2005 table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I wish to copy a single table where a particular row has a value of '76'. I then need to copy this table to another server in a separate domain.

I tried to use the export tool, but I can't restrict it to rows that have a value of 76 only

What's the best way to go about it?

Comment: Easiest is probably exporting the table and importing it if its a one time thing.  If its a regular thing, link the servers, then you can run queries and inserts across domains.

Comment: `select * into myExportTable where value = '76'` then use the export tool on `myExportTable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right Click your database:
Your server and database is already selected.
The easiest way if its not a regular thing then you could probably create a file.
Lets say abc.txt on your desktop.
Choose the flat file destination and then select the file.abc.txt in this case.
Format your wish. I like to use delimited and text qualifier " and since there are no column names and no data in our file uncheck the column names in the first row. Next select write a query to specify the data to transfer.
Lets assume you have a table TblUsers with columns username, password, value.

your query will be:

```
Select * from tblUsers where value = '76'
```

Next (Make changes if you wish, I like to leave the defaults) > Click edit mappings > Next > Finish!

Then go to your destination server and database and then do almost the same thing but import.
Thats it!